# Blocking an IR camera

Tags: optics, waves, camera, material-science

What kind of material would be best to block an IR camera?

Would Silicon work? (e.g the Silicon typically used in iPhone cases)

Rather than covering the object/subject, I'm interested in fully blocking the actual camera, so it is unable to receive any IR information.

Thanks!

Comment: you should state what wavelengths you are talking about. IR and cameras usually involve two completely different wavelength ranges, one is usually called NIR (near-IR, around 800-900 nm just near red) and the other is heat radiation, longer waves of maybe 1000-12000 nm. both are widely used for surveillance cameras although NIR is much more common and cheaper.

Comment: I don't have access to the specific wavelength, but the IR device is technically considered a sensor, not a camera.

Comment: i think you have to be a bit more specific than that.. what's it used for?

Comment: It's basically a motion sensor that functions in the dark - does that help?

Comment: [Silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon) is a metal; [silicone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicone) is a rubbery substance. Also, are you trying to block *just* IR but keep visible, or trying to nullify the camera entirely? In the latter case you'd be hard pressed to find *any* common material that lets IR through.

Comment: @user27516 What exactly is the application here? Why are you trying to block a motion sensor?

Comment: @ChrisWhite Thanks for the distinction - I'm talking about Silicone in this instance. The goal is to nullify the camera entirely. So to your knowledge, Silicone would not let IR through?

Comment: @tpg2114 the goal is to stop an IR camera from receiving data. Motivation is to protect personal privacy.

Comment: A piece of thick black paper will fully block IR camera from receiving data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular acrylic (plexiglass) will block more infrared than glass. And there are new formulations specifically designed to block IR. There are also special IR blocking polycarbonate (bulletproof) materials as well.

Some examples:
- Acrylic: Optix LRB 
- Polycarbonate: Lexan Solar Control IR

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, regular old glass that you would use in windows of a house or car absorbs infrared radiation. So if you hid behind a plate of glass, a camera would not pick up the IR signal.

Comment: who would have thought! What about silicon though, or other materials? I'm looking to cover the IR sensor itself, rather than moving myself (or the subject) behind an object?

Comment: @user27516 I don't know about other materials -- but you could just cover the sensor with glass.

Answer (score 0):

Electrical tape is opaque to IR (and visible) light.

Answer (score -1):

How about water? Blocks IR insanely! Have a look at [Wikipedia: EM-Absorption by Water](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_absorption_by_water) for detailed information.

P.S.: Please consider formally accepting an answer.